# What happens if someone signs up for Netflix on a locked credit card?

Tags: credit-card

When you lock a credit card, recurring auto-payments will continue to get paid through the card. What happens if I use a locked card to sign up for Netflix? Will the payment after the "free trial" ends go through since it is a recurring payment, or will it get denied since it is a new charge?

Comment: Even if for some reason you manage to sign up for Netflix with a locked card or one which expires in 3 weeks Netflix would simply suspend your account once they fail to receive payment from your card.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to do that in the first place. Netflix will check that the card is valid when you sign up (even though they may be giving you a free trial and not actually charging you yet). They'll see it's not legitimate and disallow you from using it.

An alternate way of explaining this is from the issuing bank's perspective. If the card is locked and then a brand new merchant attempts to set up a preauthorized transaction, the bank will deny the transaction.

The intent of locking a card is to stop *new* activity, not *all* activity or all non-recurring activity. Recurring payments that were established prior to the card being locked are allowed, but establishment of new recurring payments will not be allowed.

Comment: So a card is deemed illegitimate if it's locked?

Comment: For the purpose of authorizing a new transaction, yes.

Comment: If I sign up for a free trial of Netflix, then lock my card to avoid recurring payments, will it still go through since it was a preauthorized, recurring transaction?

Comment: If the card was not locked when you first signed up, likely yes. It's hard to precisely answer an exact scenario because it will depend on the timing of when and how the merchant submits the transactions, how your issuing bank treats locked cards (policies aren't completely uniform) and exactly when you locked it. If you are concerned about how your specific bank would handle this, you should call them and ask.

Comment: @Johnny - if your goal is to get the free trial and not get charged, you could just set a reminder to cancel at the end of the trial before the payment is processed.

Comment: @TTT That is ultimately my goal, but I thought this might be a failproof method without any manual intervention

Comment: @Johnny - Sometimes taking advantage of free offers comes with a small amount of responsibility. ;) But I understand your motivation. I sometimes forget to cancel things too...

Comment: @TTT: And some merchants (probably not including Netflix) simply make it nearly impossible to make your request for cancellation known to them.  In many cases "Just cancel" is easier said than done.

Comment: @BenVoigt - so true. I've had paid services that forced me to call to cancel, and then wait on hold for 20 minutes...

Comment: @TTT At some point, if the canceling process is burdensome enough, I feel justified in just doing a chargeback. Still a hassle, but at least now the merchant is facing financial consequences.

Comment: @Acccumulation Except credit cards will often side with the seller... had a case where we lost over $500 because we e-mailed to cancel before the deadline (this was the only way to cancel) and despite sending all the documentation on this, the CC company STILL sided with the seller because "we had an existing relationship with them"

Comment: @BenVoigt But I believe you can cancel Netflix immediately after you start the trial, and still use it for the remainder of the trial.  Since its canceled, they won't attempt to bill, but the trail viewing period remains active.  just like if you paid for the month but canceled a week after, you'd still have three weeks left.  HBO was like this for me.

Comment: @Michael You have no legal obligation to pay for charges you didn't authorize. I guess you may feel it's better to pay than to have them put it on your credit report, but simply refusing to pay is an option. How recently and what network? And did you bring it up with the network, or just the issuer bank? Visa has a zero fraud liability guarantee.

Comment: *That is ultimately my goal* - sign up using your card, and then call your bank and tell them to remove the Netflix authorization before any charge goes through. You don't have to literally lock your entire card, you just have to revoke Netflix's permission to use it.

Comment: @Acccumulation It was several years ago. I'll just say it was a major card, but not Visa or Mastercard.  The charge showed up, it was disputed, we submitted documentation (basically just a copy of the e-mail we sent before the cut-off time requesting cancellation which the seller never acknowledged); they sided with the seller because "we had an existing relationship and authorization for a recurring charge".  While it was in dispute the charge was suspended but afterwards it was put back on the statement.  What was I supposed to do, simply not pay that portion of the card statement?